# Why doesn't Scrapy save it to json file?

Tags: python, json, scrapy

I am new to Scrapy and I made a simple program to get the title tag from the page qoutes.toscrape.com. I tried to get the tag in the terminal and it works, but when I try to extract it as a json file, I get an empty json file.

```
scrapy crawl zillow -o output.json
```

What could be the problem?

Here is my code:

```
import scrapy

class ZillowSpider(scrapy.Spider):
  name = "zillow"
  start_urls = [
    "https://quotes.toscrape.com/"
  ]

  def parse(self, response):
    price = response.css("title::text").get()
```

I tried googling and chat gpt but can't find the solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside `.parse` method you need to yield all the data you want to extract and save:

```py
def parse(self, response):
    price = response.css("title::text").get()
    yield {"price": price}
```

[Link to official tutorial](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#extracting-data-in-our-spider)